# How do I prevent padding from adding space on the right side of vertical orientation phone browsers?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an unordered list with a background image to substitute for the list style. I am using padding to get it to look how I want, but it seems that any padding I utilize adds annoying extra white space to the right side of the browser when I am viewing on a phone in vertical orientation.

I am testing on an S4 galaxy and the Iphone 5 as well, both on their included browsers.

Whenever I take away the "padding-left" this extra whitespace goes away. So, I guess I am looking for one of two solutions:

1. How can I style the background image so there is roughly fifteen pixels space between the check mark image and the text?
2. How do I use padding without it creating this undesirable extra white space on the right edge of the viewport?

html:

```
                <ul>
                   <li>bullet point one</li>
                   <li>bullet point two</li>
                   <li>bullet point three</li>
                </ul>
```

CSS:

```
 ul li{
       background-image: url("../images/check-small.png");
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position:0 50%;       
       list-style:none;
       color:#FFF;
       font-size:12px;
       margin-top:4px;
       padding-left:15px
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a fiddle please?

Comment: Or a link to test site ?